# Random Multiplication Questions

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a piece of code for school to ask random multiplication question, count the number of questions, and the number of questions correct. When I run this code it comes up with an error message saying:

> TypeError: `question()` takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

What can I do to fix this? .
Here is my code so far:

```
import random
noqc=0              #noqc = number of questions correct
noqtrack=1         #noqtrack = "number of questions tracker" 
def question():       
        x=random.randint(0,12)
        z=random.randint(0,12)
        y=("What is", x, "times", z, "?")
        a=int(input(y))
        if a==x*z:
                print("Correct")
                noqc=noqc+1
        else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was:",x*z,)          
noq=int(input("How many questions would you like to do?"))     #noq = number of questions
for i in range(0, noq):
        print(noqtrack)
        noqtrack=noqtrack+1  
        question(noqc)    #<------
```

Comment: `def question(noqc)` instead of `def question()`.

Comment: Or, call the function with no argument (i.e. just `question()`) and write `global noqc` in the function definition.

Answer (score 2):

The error is arising because the definition of the function `question()` does not take any arguments(positional arguments to be exact) but you are instead calling `question(noqc)` with the argument `noqc`.

One way to correct your code might be to return the value from the `question` function. That is return `1` if answer is correct otherwise return `0`.

**Try this:**

```
import random
noqc=0              #noqc = number of questions correct
noqtrack=1         #noqtrack = "number of questions tracker" 

def question():
    x = random.randint(0, 12)
    z = random.randint(0, 12)
    y = ("What is", x, "times", z, "?")
    a = int(input(y))
    if a == x*z:
        print("Correct")
        return 1
    else:
        print("Wrong, the answer was:", x*z,)
        return 0


# noq = number of questions
noq = int(input("How many questions would you like to do?"))
for i in range(noq):
    print(noqtrack)
    noqtrack = noqtrack+1
    noqc += question()
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to what Shubham said, I think you lack of understanding of how Python scopes work. Here you have some samples of code that illustrates you how the local and the global scopes work.

```
x = 0
def wont_modify_1(x):
  # this will make a copy of x in the local scope
  # then increment it by one
  x += 1
  # prints 1
  print ("x inside wont_modify_1 = {}".format(x))

wont_modify_1(x)
# prints 0, the variable outside the function wasn't modified
print ("x outside wont_modify_1 = {}".format(x))


y = 0
def won_t_modify_2():
  # variable y does not exist in this scope
  # it will be created here and assigned 1 to it
  y = 1
  # prints the value of the local variable, 1
  print ("y inside wont_modify_2 = {}".format(y))

won_t_modify_2()
# the global variable is a different object
# it wasn't modified, it prints 0
print ("y outside wont_modify_2 = {}".format(y))


z = 0
def won_t_modify_3():
  # z does not exists in this scope, so it can't be incremented by one
  # this will raise an error
  # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment
  z += 1
  print ("z inside wont_modify_3 = {}".format(z))

won_t_modify_3()
print ("z outside wont_modify_3 = {}".format(z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you really need to use more descriptive variable names...

instead of `noqc` try using `numOfCorrectAwnsers` or even something as simple as `correct` which will be a lot more readable and will almost surely get you more points in your class.

Also I would approach this loop differently:

```
noq = int(input("How many questions would you like to do?"))
for i in range(noq):
    print(noqtrack)
    noqtrack = noqtrack+1
    noqc += question()
```

Try changing it to:

```
numOfCorrectQuestions = int(input("How many questions would you like to do?"))
while numOfCorrectAwnsers < numOfCorrectQuestions:
    question()
    numOfTotalQuestions += 1
```